# Cassandra multi-column IN parameters binding in java datastax driver

Tags: java, cassandra, prepared-statement, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I'm trying to create the following query in cassandra using datastax java driver and it runs fine:

```
SELECT * FROM "TEST".my_cf WHERE jobName = 'job1' AND siteId = 'account1' 
 AND date = 12345 and (consumerId) in (('consumer3'));
```

where `consumerId` is part of the clustering key (not the last one - that's why I have to use multi-column restriction).

However, the driver seems to not support it, and I'm not sure where to put the brackets.

I'm getting the following error:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 2:122 missing EOF at 'in'
```

Any idea how can I bind multi-column query parameters using the driver (and prepared statement)?

Thanks